# Cannot calling directly python from the command prompt: need to enter the full installation path

Tags: python, windows, command-prompt

On my PC at work which has Windows 10, I've installed Python. However when I'm trying to call from the command prompt, I get the following result (**Picture 1**) and I have to manually enter the path to open python (**Picture 2**). In order to be able to install all the libraries, what should I do in ordert to be able to directly call python as in **Picture 1**? I tried to add the path to the user environment as in **Picture 3**, as suggest below but, I still get the exact same error message as in **Picture 1**

**Picture 1**

[image]

**Picture 2**

[image]

**Picture 3**
[image]

Comment: add the python path to your environment variables

Comment: Add python path and Scripts path to System variable by just search system variable (Enviornment) and go to advance and add complete path to path section

Comment: read: https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/

Comment: If you installed the py.exe launcher for all users, just run `py`, or `py -3.7` to be precise. To install packages, run `py -m pip install <...>`. You can add the installation and scripts directories to `PATH` if you really need a particular python.exe and pip.exe, but it becomes a maintenance chore when upgrading to a new major version, or if you need to switch between versions. Commonly in development it's better to create and activate a virtual environment, e.g. `py -m venv env37` and then `env37\Scripts\activate.bat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see how to addpath on windows 10

https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/

[image: add python path as shown here!]

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Ibrahim. I tried your answer and uploaded the screenshot of the implementation but it still doesn't work. what am I missing?

Comment: Hi, add your python path inside the variable "Path". ( In your screenshot picture3, below the selected OneDrive variable. click the Path variable then add python path  inside it) Then you must close and open the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue when i'm new to python.
So, I suggest you to re-install the python while installing there will be option to add '.exe' file to the path then you can directly call python interpreter in your command prompt.